# Join to Table-valued Function failing

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I've come across a join onto a table-valued function that is failing and I cannot explain it.  I've created a test script below and I am running this on SQL Server 2008 R2

Can anyone understand why at the end of the test script the first SELECT statement works and the second statement doesn't work?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test (Setting INT NOT NULL, Value NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL)

GO

INSERT  dbo.Test (Setting, Value)
SELECT  3151, '2~-10011;2~-10012'

GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CTESplitChunk] (@list  nvarchar(MAX),
                                 @delim nchar(1) = ',')
RETURNS @t TABLE (str nvarchar(4000) NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @slice nvarchar(4000),
           @textpos int,
           @maxlen  int,
           @stoppos int,
           @lastone bit

   SELECT @textpos = 1, @maxlen = 4000 - 2, @lastone = 0
   WHILE @lastone = 0
   BEGIN
      IF datalength(@list) / 2 - (@textpos - 1) >= @maxlen
      BEGIN
         SELECT @slice = substring(@list, @textpos, @maxlen)
         SELECT @stoppos = @maxlen -
                           charindex(@delim COLLATE Slovenian_BIN2, reverse(@slice))
         SELECT @slice = left(@slice, @stoppos) + @delim
         SELECT @textpos = @textpos - 1 + @stoppos + 2   -- On the other side of the comma.
      END
      ELSE
         SELECT @slice = substring(@list, @textpos, @maxlen) + @delim,
                @lastone = 1

      ;WITH csvtbl(start, stop) AS (
         SELECT start = 1,
                stop  = charindex(@delim COLLATE Slovenian_BIN2, @slice)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT start = stop + 1,
                stop  = charindex(@delim COLLATE Slovenian_BIN2,
                                  @slice, stop + 1)
         FROM   csvtbl
         WHERE  stop > 0
      )
      INSERT @t (str)
         SELECT ltrim(rtrim(
                substring(@slice, start,
                          CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop - start ELSE 0 END)))
         FROM   csvtbl
         WHERE  stop > 0
         OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
   END

   RETURN
END

GO

SELECT          Value
FROM            dbo.Test t
WHERE           t.Setting = '3151'

GO

SELECT          Value
FROM            dbo.Test t
    INNER JOIN  dbo.CTESplitChunk (t.Value, ';') s ON 1 = 1
WHERE           t.Setting = '3151'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `CROSS APPLY` to call the TVF with a correlated parameter.

```
SELECT t.Value,
       s.*
FROM   dbo.Test t
       CROSS APPLY dbo.CTESplitChunk (t.Value, ';') s
WHERE  t.Setting = '3151'
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks - it dawned on me after posting!  School boy error :-)

Comment: Well now you've added the `CROSS APPLY` into the code in the question this answer looks strange. Regarding the Why it doesn't make sense to join onto some table expression that can change its contents according to the `t.Value`. Inner joins are supposed to be commutative. How could you drive the join from the TVF?

Comment: Understood - I added that before I saw your answer - I'll remove the edit for future reference.